# Get specific line from unix command output

Tags: unix

lets say I run a command in the shell `cmd doSomething` and it shows separate lines as output, for example

```
> cmd doSomething
outputLine1
outputLine2
outputLine3
```

Is there a way to assign the 2 nd line(outputLine2) in to a variable (e.g testdir) ?
Ideally I would like to be able to use $testdir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `head` and `tail`, as follows:

```
doSomething | head -n 2 | tail -n 1
```

The `head -n 2` shows the first two output lines, the `tail -n 1` the last of those two.

For putting this into a variable:

```
variable=$(doSomething | head -n 2 | tail -n 1)
```